# How to speed up Oracle to PostgreSQL data transfer

Tags: postgresql, oracle-12c, migration, gdal, schema-migration

I have an Oracle schema that I am transferring to PostgreSQL with ogr2ogr.
This particular table has 5 columns with number(22) each. There are some 300M rows. In under 10 minutes I can transfer this table between two oracle servers over the network. `ogr2ogr` took a day to transfer 10M records and will take a month to transfer the whole table.

I suspect the problem is on the receiving end. Data is transferred to AWS PgSQL with 4 Gb ram. How to debug the bottleneck and speed up the transfer?

Comment: There is a [foreign data wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-foreign-data.html) for [Oracle](https://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/) maybe that works better

Comment: Does ogr2ogr create the indexes before it loads the data?

Comment: does ogr2ogr use single row inserts, multi-row inserts, or  streaming to `copy ... from stdin` ?  thousand-row inserts are about a hundred times faster than single row inserts, but streaming is about 10 times faster than that.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth pushing a subset to a file and loading it with copy, just to get a sense of the throughput. Copy is...legendary....for high-speed bulk loading into an empty table.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html